# How do I consolidate ddply across two columns?

Tags: r, plyr

I have some data for sites across a bunch of cities that looks about like this:

```
CITY        STATE   LAT     LON     SCORE
Jacksonville    FL  30.328539   -81.65101   5
Jacksonville    FL  30.392888   -81.67933   6
Jacksonville    FL  30.268572   -81.73987   4
Jacksonville    FL  30.348585   -81.49965   3
Lake Worth      FL  26.579714   -80.07437   6
Lake Worth      FL  26.609226   -80.12874   3
Miami       FL  25.813808   -80.2058    3
Miami       FL  25.753927   -80.27034   2
Miami       FL  25.786326   -80.2029    6
Miami       FL  25.817325   -80.19046   8
Miami       FL  25.812625   -80.2369    9
Miami       FL  25.885739   -80.23264   4
Miami       FL  25.962069   -80.14465   5
```

I want to count the records for each city and average the score. I know I could do that with ddply if the cities were unique, but they aren't. There's a "Miami, KS" or something in there. So I need to do ddply on the combined city and state. Something like:

```
ddply(sometable, .(CITY, STATE), summarise,
                            mean.score=mean(SCORE),
                            record.count=length(SCORE)
                            )
```

Is there a way to do that? I also need to grab one of the lat/lon pairs for each city. Doesn't matter which one.

Comment: Your suggested code works fine for me if I add a `Miami/KS` in there. Did you try running it?

Comment: So ... yeah. It works fine to do `.(city, state)` -- I think I was overtired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(plyr)
ddply(data,c(.(CITY),.(STATE)),summarise,count=length(SCORE),mean=mean(SCORE))
```

or you can use:

```
library(data.table)
data <- data.table(data)
data[, list(count=length(SCORE), mean=mean(SCORE)), by=c("CITY", "STATE")]
```

or this:

```
aggregate(SCORE~CITY+STATE,data,function(x) cbind(length(x),mean(x)))

       CITY STATE count     mean
1 Jacksonville    FL     4 4.500000
2   Lake Worth    FL     2 4.500000
3        Miami    FL     7 5.285714
```